# Is it possible to add `'s` or `'` (if a word ends with `s`) using only PCRE replace?

Tags: regex, pcre

Disclaimer: it's an artificial task and does not have any initial or underlying problem.

Is there a way to perform the following replacement:

```
zerkms -> zerkms'
foo -> foo's
```

using only the PCRE dialect and `replace` operation (as it is represented in https://regex101.com/ and without specific language extensions)?

I personally think it's not possible since there is no (?) way to put an arbitrary (that does not present in the original string) constant substring in a capturing match. If it was possible - then I would have a solution.

Efforts I put: well, not much here, since I haven't found any way to perform a conditional replacement in PCRE.

PS: https://regex101.com/ demos are welcomed.

PPS: the question is not about doing that at all (I know we all can use programming languages with conditionals), but about demonstrating PCRE abilities (or lack of thereof).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.conditional.php

Comment: "replace" operation?

Comment: @PHPglue I'm referring to what https://regex101.com/ calls "substitution"

Comment: I don't think you can perform a conditional substitution, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: @PHPglue the question is about language-neutral PCRE (its subset that works everywhere, compared to the perl-specific answer provided).

Comment: The first sentence in Amanda's answer should do for you.

Comment: @PHPglue the first sentence does not provide an answer whether it's possible or not to do using facilities https://regex101.com/ provides

Comment: @zerkms: Not that Perl-specific - most languages that implement regular expressions will have some syntax that allows execution of code for replacements. JavaScript and Ruby for example all do this (even though neither uses PCRE). But if you take a look at PCRE2 library documentation, there is, AFAIK, *not a single word about replacement*. If you wanted to ask "is it possible in regex101", you should have asked *that*. It's still a "no". :)

Comment: Just add "No, " in front of that.

Comment: @Amadan if it's in the answer - then it's the answer :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PCRE is about finding. Replacement is not part of PCRE, or regular expressions.

```
s/(s?)\b/$1?"s'":"'s"/eg;
```

`(s?)\b` is PCRE. The rest of it is Perl's implementation of substitution.

EDIT: "no". To spell it out: you can't do a conditional replace using PCRE because you can't do a *replace* using PCRE in the first place.

Comment: "about demonstrating PCRE abilities (or lack of thereof)" - The answer is not the "how to do it" code part, but arguing why it should not be thought as part of PCRE at all. If the question is "can I inject a string not present in the searched string into a capture group" instead of "can i do this replacement", then "no" is the answer, short by 28 characters.